# Java Duplicate Local Variable Line/Read

Tags: java

Duplicate local variable on Line 545 & 159,

examples of line

## 1

```
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { String line;
```

## 2

```
  int read; while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1) { int read;
```

## entire code

```
package scripts.BankChecker;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.tribot.api.DynamicClicking;
import org.tribot.api.input.Keyboard;
import org.tribot.api.input.Mouse;
import org.tribot.api2007.Banking;
import org.tribot.api2007.Interfaces;
import org.tribot.api2007.Login;
import org.tribot.api2007.Login.STATE;
import org.tribot.api2007.Magic;
import org.tribot.api2007.Objects;
import org.tribot.api2007.Player;
import org.tribot.api2007.Walking;
import org.tribot.api2007.WorldHopper;
import org.tribot.api2007.types.RSInterfaceChild;
import org.tribot.api2007.types.RSInterfaceMaster;
import org.tribot.api2007.types.RSItem;
import org.tribot.api2007.types.RSObject;
import org.tribot.api2007.types.RSTile;
import org.tribot.script.Script;
import org.tribot.script.ScriptManifest;
import org.tribot.script.interfaces.Painting;
import org.tribot.util.Util;

@ScriptManifest(authors={"Mentoes"}, category="Other", name="OSRS Bank Value Checker", description="Quickly check the value of OSRS accounts")
public class ScriptWorker extends Script implements Painting
{
  public static boolean guiDone = false;
  public static boolean guiOpen = false;

  public static File inFile;
  public static File outFile;
  boolean needLogin = true;
  boolean clearedResponse = false;

  boolean stopped = false;
  boolean checked = false;
  boolean checkLumbyTile = true;

  String scriptStatus = "Starting";
  String currentUsername = "";
  String currentPassword = "";


  ArrayList<String> accounts = new ArrayList();

  int bankValue = 0;
  String apiUrl = "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=";

  RSTile[] lumbridgeTiles = { new RSTile(3220, 3215, 0), new RSTile(3221, 3215, 0), new RSTile(3222, 3215, 0), 
    new RSTile(3223, 3215, 0), new RSTile(3224, 3215, 0), new RSTile(3225, 3215, 0), 

    new RSTile(3220, 3216, 0), new RSTile(3221, 3216, 0), new RSTile(3222, 3216, 0), new RSTile(3223, 3216, 0), 
    new RSTile(3224, 3216, 0), new RSTile(3225, 3216, 0), 

    new RSTile(3220, 3217, 0), new RSTile(3221, 3217, 0), new RSTile(3222, 3217, 0), new RSTile(3223, 3217, 0), 
    new RSTile(3224, 3217, 0), new RSTile(3225, 3217, 0), 

    new RSTile(3220, 3218, 0), new RSTile(3221, 3218, 0), new RSTile(3222, 3218, 0), new RSTile(3223, 3218, 0), 
    new RSTile(3224, 3218, 0), new RSTile(3225, 3218, 0), 

    new RSTile(3220, 3219, 0), new RSTile(3221, 3219, 0), new RSTile(3222, 3219, 0), new RSTile(3223, 3219, 0), 
    new RSTile(3224, 3219, 0), new RSTile(3225, 3219, 0), 

    new RSTile(3220, 3220, 0), new RSTile(3221, 3220, 0), new RSTile(3222, 3220, 0), new RSTile(3223, 3220, 0), 
    new RSTile(3224, 3220, 0), new RSTile(3225, 3220, 0), 

    new RSTile(3220, 3221, 0), new RSTile(3221, 3221, 0), new RSTile(3222, 3221, 0), new RSTile(3223, 3221, 0), 
    new RSTile(3224, 3221, 0), new RSTile(3225, 3221, 0), 

    new RSTile(3220, 3222, 0), new RSTile(3221, 3222, 0), new RSTile(3222, 3222, 0), new RSTile(3223, 3222, 0), 
    new RSTile(3224, 3222, 0), new RSTile(3225, 3222, 0) };

  RSTile stairTileBottom = new RSTile(3205, 3209);
  RSTile stairTileMid = new RSTile(3205, 3209, 1);
  RSTile stairTileTop = new RSTile(3205, 3209, 2);
  RSTile doorTile = new RSTile(3216, 3219);
  RSTile door2Tile = new RSTile(3215, 3211);
  RSTile bankTile = new RSTile(3209, 3220);

  Point worldSwitchButton = new Point(55, 481);
  Point world317 = new Point(251, 395);
  Point welcomeMessageButton = new Point(400, 335);
  Point usernameSpot = new Point(474, 259);
  Point passwordSpot = new Point(437, 275);
  Rectangle tryAgainButton = new Rectangle(316, 261, 134, 30);
  Rectangle loginButton = new Rectangle(235, 306, 134, 30);
  Rectangle cancleButton = new Rectangle(396, 308, 134, 30);
  Rectangle existingUserButton = new Rectangle(395, 275, 134, 30);

  public ScriptWorker() {}

  public void onPaint(Graphics g) { g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString("Mentoes Bank Checker", 10, 68);
    g.drawString("Status: " + scriptStatus, 10, 83);
    g.drawString("Accounts left: " + accounts.size(), 10, 95);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawString("Current bank value: " + bankValue, 10, 110);

    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.drawString("Login State: " + Login.getLoginState(), 10, 130);
    g.drawString("Login response: " + Login.getLoginResponse(), 10, 400);
  }

  enum State
  {
      NEED_TO_LOGIN("NEED_TO_LOGIN", 0), 
      ON_WELCOME_SCREEN("ON_WELCOME_SCREEN", 1), 
      WALK_TO_BANK("WALK_TO_BANK", 2), 
      IN_BANK("IN_BANK", 3), 
      PIN_OPEN("PIN_OPEN", 4), 
      CALCULATE_BANK("CALCULATE_BANK", 5), 
      DONE("DONE", 6), 
      TFA("TFA", 7), 
      TUTORIAL_ISLAND("TUTORIAL_ISLAND", 8), 
      FAILED_LOGIN("FAILED_LOGIN", 9), 
      F2P("F2P", 10);

      private State(final String s, final int n) {
      }
  }

  public void run()
  {
    println("----Started----");
    setLoginBotState(false);

    while (!guiDone) {
      if (!guiOpen) {
        BankValueGUI.main(null);
        guiOpen = true;
      }
      scriptStatus = "GUI open";
      sleep(300L);
    }

    if (guiDone) {
      println("GUI done");
      println("Infile: " + inFile.getAbsolutePath());

      scriptStatus = "Populating Array";
      try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { String line;
          accounts.add(line.trim());
        }
        br.close();
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        stopped = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        stopped = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      while (!stopped) {
        scriptStatus = "Getting game state";
        ScriptWorker.State currentState = state();

        if (currentState != null) {
          switch (currentState) {
          case TFA: 
            handleTutorialIsland();
            break;
          case PIN_OPEN: 
            handleTFA();
            break;
          case NEED_TO_LOGIN: 
            handleBankCalculation();
            break;
          case ON_WELCOME_SCREEN: 
            handleDone();
            break;
          case FAILED_LOGIN: 
            handleInBank();
            break;
          case CALCULATE_BANK: 
            handleLogin();
            break;
          case DONE: 
            handleWelcomeScreen();
            break;
          case IN_BANK: 
            handlePinOpen();
            break;
          case F2P: 
            handleWalkToBank();
            break;
          case WALK_TO_BANK: 
            handleF2P();
            break;
          case TUTORIAL_ISLAND: 
            handleFailedLogin();
          }

        }

        sleep(100L);
      }
      println("----Stopping----");
    }
  }

  private void handleF2P() {
    scriptStatus = "Switching to f2p world";

    WorldHopper.changeWorld(316);
    sleep(200L);

    Mouse.clickBox(loginButton, 1);
    sleep(4000L);
  }

  private void handleFailedLogin() {
    scriptStatus = "Failed login";

    Mouse.clickBox(cancleButton, 1);
    sleep(200L);

    Mouse.clickBox(cancleButton, 1);
    sleep(200L);

    clearedResponse = false;
    sleep(200L);
  }

  private void handleTutorialIsland() {
    scriptStatus = "On tut island, logging out";

    Login.logout();
    sleep(200L);
  }

  private void handleTFA() {
    scriptStatus = "Handling 2FA";

    Mouse.clickBox(cancleButton, 1);
    sleep(200L);
    clearedResponse = true;
    sleep(200L);
  }

  private void manualLogin(String username, String password, boolean login)
  {
    Mouse.clickBox(existingUserButton, 1);
    sleep(200L);

    Mouse.click(usernameSpot, 1);
    sleep(100L);
    Keyboard.typeString(username);
    sleep(200L);

    Mouse.click(passwordSpot, 1);
    sleep(100L);
    Keyboard.typeString(password);
    sleep(200L);

    if (login) {
      Mouse.clickBox(loginButton, 1);
      sleep(7000L);
    } else {
      Mouse.clickBox(cancleButton, 1);
      sleep(200L);
    }

    if (Login.getLoginResponse().contains("too many")) {
      println("Stopped due to too many logins");
      println("Response: " + Login.getLoginResponse());
      stopped = true;
      return;
    }

    clearedResponse = true;
  }

  private void handleDone() {
    scriptStatus = "Saving and logging out";

    Login.logout();
    try
    {
      FileWriter w = new FileWriter(Util.getWorkingDirectory() + File.separator + "OSRSBankValues.txt", true);
      w.write(currentUsername + " - " + bankValue + System.lineSeparator());
      w.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try
    {
      FileWriter w = new FileWriter(Util.getWorkingDirectory() + File.separator + "Tried_Accounts.txt", true);
      w.write(currentUsername + ":" + currentPassword + System.lineSeparator());
      w.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    checked = false;
    bankValue = 0;
    checkLumbyTile = true;
    sleep(200L);
  }

  private int getItemValue(int id)
  {
    try {
      String price = readUrl(apiUrl + String.valueOf(id)).split(",")[8].split(":")[1];
      String price2 = price.substring(0, price.length() - 1);
      return Integer.parseInt(price2);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace(); }
    return 0;
  }

  private void handleBankCalculation()
  {
    scriptStatus = "Calculting Bank Value";

    Banking.depositEquipment();
    Banking.depositAll();
    sleep(300L);

    RSItem[] bankItems = Banking.getAll();
    for (RSItem i : bankItems) {
      if (i.getID() == 995) {
        bankValue += i.getStack();
      } else {
        bankValue += i.getStack() * getItemValue(i.getID());
        sleep(100L);
      }
    }
    Banking.close();
    checked = true;
    sleep(200L);
  }

  private void handlePinOpen() {
    scriptStatus = "Bank pin";

    Banking.close();
    if ((!Banking.isPinScreenOpen()) && (!Banking.isBankScreenOpen())) {
      checked = true;
      Banking.close();
    }

    sleep(200L);
  }

  private void handleInBank() {
    scriptStatus = "Opening bank";

    Banking.openBank();
    sleep(200L);
  }

  private void waitUntilIdle() {
    scriptStatus = "Waiting for idle";

    while ((Player.isMoving()) || (Player.getAnimation() != -1)) {
      sleep(100L);
    }
  }

  private void handleWalkToBank() {
    scriptStatus = "Walking to the bank";














    if ((Player.getPosition().getX() > 3223) || (Player.getPosition().getX() < 3200) || (Player.getPosition().getY() > 3234) || (Player.getPosition().getY() < 3200)) {
      Magic.selectSpell("Lumbridge Home Teleport");
      sleep(17000L);
      waitUntilIdle();
    }
    else {
      int currentPlane = Player.getPosition().getPlane();

      if (currentPlane == 0) {
        if ((Player.getPosition().equals(doorTile)) || (Player.getPosition().distanceTo(doorTile) <= 3)) {
          Walking.walkTo(door2Tile);
          sleep(500L);
          waitUntilIdle();
        } else if ((Player.getPosition().equals(door2Tile)) || (Player.getPosition().distanceTo(door2Tile) <= 3)) {
          Walking.walkTo(stairTileBottom);
          sleep(500L);
          waitUntilIdle();
        } else if ((Player.getPosition().equals(stairTileBottom)) || (Player.getPosition().distanceTo(stairTileBottom) <= 2)) {
          RSObject[] stairs = Objects.find(100, new int[] { 16671 });
          if ((stairs != null) && (stairs.length >= 1)) {
            DynamicClicking.clickRSObject(stairs[0], "Climb-up");
            waitUntilIdle();
            sleep(100L);
          }
        } else {
          Walking.walkTo(doorTile);
          sleep(500L);
          waitUntilIdle();
        }
      } else if (currentPlane == 1) {
        RSObject[] stairs = Objects.find(100, new int[] { 16672 });
        if ((stairs != null) && (stairs.length >= 1)) {
          DynamicClicking.clickRSObject(stairs[0], "Climb-up");
          sleep(200L);
        }
      } else if (currentPlane == 2) {
        Walking.walkTo(bankTile);
        sleep(100L);
        waitUntilIdle();
      }
    }
  }

  private void handleWelcomeScreen() {
    scriptStatus = "Handling welcome screen";

    Mouse.click(welcomeMessageButton, 1);
    sleep(200L);
  }

  private void handleLogin() {
    scriptStatus = "Logging in";








    if (accounts.isEmpty()) {
      stopped = true;
    }
    else if ((((String)accounts.get(0)).contains(":")) && (((String)accounts.get(0)).length() >= 1)) {
      String username = ((String)accounts.get(0)).split(":")[0];
      String password = ((String)accounts.get(0)).split(":")[1];
      currentUsername = username;
      currentPassword = password;
      accounts.remove(0);

      manualLogin(username, password, true);
      sleep(500L);
    } else {
      accounts.remove(0);
    }
  }

  private ScriptWorker.State state()
  {
    if (Login.getLoginState().equals(Login.STATE.LOGINSCREEN)) {
      if (((Login.getLoginResponse().contains("unsuccessful")) && (clearedResponse)) || 
        ((Login.getLoginResponse().contains("recover")) && (clearedResponse)) || 
        ((Login.getLoginResponse().contains("logged in")) && (clearedResponse)) || 
        ((Login.getLoginResponse().contains("website")) && (clearedResponse)) || (
        (Login.getLoginResponse().contains("disabled")) && (clearedResponse))) {
        return ScriptWorker.State.FAILED_LOGIN;
      }

      if (Login.getLoginResponse().contains("members")) {
        return ScriptWorker.State.F2P;
      }

      if (needLogin) {
        return ScriptWorker.State.NEED_TO_LOGIN;
      }

      return ScriptWorker.State.TFA;
    }

    if (Login.getLoginState().equals(Login.STATE.UNKNOWN)) {
      return ScriptWorker.State.TFA;
    }

    if (Login.getLoginState().equals(Login.STATE.WELCOMESCREEN)) {
      return ScriptWorker.State.ON_WELCOME_SCREEN;
    }

    if (Login.getLoginState().equals(Login.STATE.INGAME)) {
      RSInterfaceMaster[] ints = Interfaces.getAll();
      for (RSInterfaceMaster i : ints) {
        if ((i.getChild(0).getUID() == 24313856) || (i.getUID() == 35913742)) {
          return ScriptWorker.State.TUTORIAL_ISLAND;
        }
      }

      if (Banking.isPinScreenOpen()) {
        return ScriptWorker.State.PIN_OPEN;
      }

      if (Banking.isBankScreenOpen()) {
        return ScriptWorker.State.CALCULATE_BANK;
      }

      if (Banking.isInBank()) {
        if (!checked) {
          return ScriptWorker.State.IN_BANK;
        }
        return ScriptWorker.State.DONE;
      }


      return ScriptWorker.State.WALK_TO_BANK;
    }

    return null;
  }



  private static String readUrl(String urlString)
    throws Exception
  {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
      URL url = new URL(urlString);
      reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
      StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

      char[] chars = new char['Ѐ'];
      int read; while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1) { int read;
        buffer.append(chars, 0, read);
      }
      return buffer.toString();
    } finally {
      if (reader != null) {
        reader.close();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @LucyBeale whats your question?

Comment: Don't just dump code without a question. Don't just dump code at all. I assume you have an error? What is not clear about it?

Comment: @NullSaint How do I fix this error?

Comment: To fix the error, remove the duplicate declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the duplicate declarations. Example:

```
    try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { String line;
      accounts.add(line.trim());
    }
    br.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  }
```

If you defined `String line` above the while loop, do not define it again inside the while loop. The variable is still in scope.

```
    try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
    // PROBABLY DELETE THIS LINE --> String line;
    while ((String line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
      // PROBABLY REMOVE THIS ONE TOO --> String line;
      accounts.add(line.trim());
    }
    br.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  }
```

However, there is too much code here to see which definition should be removed. Generally, keep the scope of variables as limited as possible.